# Switch user to root by SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NET in order to get some informations of an external tape drive. Connecting and executing some basic commands works perfectly fine for me:

```cs
ConnectionInfo connNfo = new ConnectionInfo("10.12.2.97", 22, "loginuser",
new AuthenticationMethod[]
{
// Password based Authentication
new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("loginuser","password")
}
);

using (var client = new SshClient(connNfo))
{
    client.Connect();

    //This command works fine
    using (var cmd = client.CreateCommand("ls"))
    {
        string result = cmd.Execute();
    }
}
```

But now i have to switch to root user in order to execute extended commands i need. Initially logging in with root user is not possible because of security restrictions. Referring to this post [How to run commands by sudo and enter password by ssh .net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41555597/how-to-run-commands-by-sudo-and-enter-password-by-ssh-net-c-sharp) i tried this code block:

```cs
using (var cmd = ssh.RunCommand("echo 'rootpassword' | sudo -u root -S fsstate"))
{
if (cmd.ExitStatus == 0)
    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result);
else
    Console.WriteLine(cmd.Error);
}
```

But then i always receive this error message:

**sudo: unknown user: root 

sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin**

Update 1:
[Working PuTTY commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThpIM.png)

What i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo` and  `sudo -u root` on the server in question without ssh.net?

Comment: @ikkentim Yes. I tried it with Putty without any issues. Just typed in 'sudo root' and 'rootpassword' and it worked.

Comment: But does `echo 'rootpassword' | sudo -u root -S fsstate` work in PuTTY?

Comment: I'm guessing ssh.net's `.RunCommand` might not be able to handle pipes ( the | ). I'm not sure if this is true, you'd have to consult the manual. I'm afraid I can't help you much further than that.

Comment: @ikkentim `RunCommand` does not process the command in any way. If there's problem with a pipe, it's on the remote side, not on SSH.NET side. Though the error message OP is getting does not suggest any problem with "pipe".

Comment: Ok i checked `echo 'rootpassword' | sudo -u root -S fsstate` with PuTTY. I get the same error message like described in my post. But when i perform `sudo rootsh` on SSH.NET (which works fine with PuTTY) i got following error message: **sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**. I dont have much experience with SSH Terminal, sorry :)

Comment: And if you do `sudo -u root -S`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl `sudo -u root -S` doesn't work both on PuTTY and SSH.NET. Igot following error message: **sudo: unknown user: root
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin**. In fact only `sudo root` works with PuTTY.

Comment: `sudo root` is a strange syntax. It says `sudo` to execute `root` "command" (not to switch to `root` user). Is this what you are actually doing? Then you can try `sudo root -S`.

Comment: `sudo root -S` returns invalid option by PuTTY. I update my post with the commands i successfully performned on PuTTY. Hopefully that helps. `rootsh` is my `root` user.

Comment: OK, than your `sudo` is not the common Linux `sudo`. It's difficult to help you, unless you give us some reference for your version of `sudo`.

Comment: I think i struggle with the problem described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error) I'm gonna try fix this like that. Thank you for helping me.